# Is a 'column vector' actually a vector or a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, soft-question

I've read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639184/how-is-a-column-or-row-matrix-considered-a-vector) and posted [my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491510/row-and-column-vector-representation-for-euclidian-vector-spaces), but I think I will write a more direct question related to this topic, I understand how row and column vectors can be used to *represent* vectors as answered in the question, but is it actually a vector, or a way of us trying to give the idea of components by putting them in a matrix? For example, Euclidian vectors have no concept of 'transpose', if the components are equal, its the same vector, yet row and column vectors are transpose of each other?

A question I have is say we have:

$y = \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
         \end{bmatrix}$

Can we have also $y = [x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]$?

as then we have
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{1} \\
  x_{2} \\   
  x_{3}
  \end{bmatrix} = $[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]$

and this gives $y=y^T$ which would be an incorrect result.

Comment: Your link is to Stackoverflow, not to a specific post.

Comment: There is widespread usage of either form ($n\times1$ matrix or vector of length $n$). As long as the conventions are consistent, there is no practical difference between the two. That being said, I believe that usually vectors are represented by *columns* more often than *rows*.

Comment: Fixed the link. Sorry.

Comment: A vector is just an element of a vector space. A column vector is an element of the vector space of all column vectors.  So in that sense, all column vectors are vectors. As for whether a given vector "is" a column vector, this is just a matter of convention and depends on the mood of the author.

Comment: As @JairTaylor mentioned, it's just a question of convention. There is a bijective relationship between the N-dimensional vector and a $1\times N$ or an $N\times 1$ matrix. If there would be any use, one can have any other bijective relationship to any higher dimensional matrix space.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134809/are-there-any-differences-between-tensors-and-multidimensional-arrays) on tensors versus multidimensional arrays is not quite a duplicate, but does get at the ambiguity (stemming from omitted context) that makes your question difficult to answer.

Comment: Many different objects are called “vectors” in different contexts. Whenever we have a vector space, the elements of that space might be called “vectors”. In my mind, the elements of $\mathbb R^n$ are column vectors, and a “column vector” is just an $n \times 1$ matrix. I will also refer to the elements of $\mathbb R^n$ as “vectors”, assuming that the meaning is clear from context.

Comment: I've definitely seen the notation [1 2 3]^T to indicate a column vector when it is inconvenient to typeset it (such as inline in text).

Comment: @littleO we could also consider $R^n$ as having members of row vectors all the way to $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Euclidian vectors have no concept of 'transpose', if the components are equal, its the same vector,

That's right. A column vector and a row vector with identical corresponding entries $$\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
         \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad[x_{1} \;\;x_{2} \;\;x_{3}]$$ are the exact same vector in $\mathbb R^3,$ just formatted differently (column form versus row form).

> yet row and column vectors are transpose of each other?

Don't forget, we are never capriciously alternating between row and column vectors: in any given problem/modelling/text, we don't concurrently deal with both formats, so there is no context for asking whether, as Euclidean vectors, $\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
         \end{bmatrix}$ transposes $[x_{1} \;\;x_{2} \;\;x_{3}].$ Reiterating our above agreement: the concept of transpose is inapplicable in Euclidean space, and in the context of $\mathbb R^3,\;\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
         \end{bmatrix}$ and $[x_{1} \;\;x_{2} \;\;x_{3}]$ are the same object, just at different parties.

A matrix is a data structure, and a $3\times1$ matrix can be *framed* as a (column) vector in $\mathbb R^3$ while a $1\times3$ matrix can be *framed* as a (row) vector in $\mathbb R^3.$ These two matrices are transposes of each other: $$\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
         \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad[x_{1} \;\;x_{2} \;\;x_{3}].$$

> I understand how row and column vectors can be used to represent vectors, but is it actually a vector, or a way of us trying to give the idea of components by putting them in a matrix?

Get rid of the notion that a directed line segment (i.e., arrow) is the real vector and that its corresponding 3x1 matrix (i.e., column vector, i.e., slim vertical data structure containing its $x,y,z$ components) is just its representation: an Euclidean vector is an abstract object and both are valid manifestations of it; in $\mathbb R^7,$ which representation is more practical?

> $ y=\begin{bmatrix}
>            x_{1} \\
>            x_{2} \\
>            x_{3}
>          \end{bmatrix} = [x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]\;?$
>
> this gives $y=y^T$

You need to clarify your notation. For example, from page 39 of David Lay's *Linear Algebra*:
[image]

Following this convention, $$ y=\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
         \end{bmatrix} = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \ne [x_{1} \;\;x_{2} \;\;x_{3}]=y^T.$$

Comment: I also notice we sometimes write something like a column vector but rounded instead of square like ( ) and vertical entries, is this a vector specific notation? When we use these columns and rows are we essentially representing the vector by writing it in a matrix? About never switching between the notations, I have seen definitions of cross-product (I believe) as a matrix product of a row and column vectors.

Comment: 1.  That ( versus [ preference is just a Math vs. Enginn/CompSci thing: mathematicians tend to use ( since quicker to hand-write; others prefer [. $\quad$ 2. You mean dot product there, not cross product. Yes, and in that context the Euclidean vectors are just being special (slim) matrices. To be clear, I should also point out the (annoyingly) common practice of interchangeably, within the same context, using column and row format (without any entry-separating comma, unlike in that David Lay example) to represent the same Euclidean vector; charitably, this is merely abusing notation.

Comment: I just find it a bit strange to use both row and column vectors but we can just say that if $V$ is a column vector then $V^T$ is the row vector, the idea of it as a 'co-ordinate representation' instead of the vector itself makes it make more sense, essentially we put the co-ordinates in a matrix, can a tuple like $(1,2,3)$ be equal to a column vector, as you give in your example?

Comment: 1. "*I just find it a bit strange to use both row and column vectors*" If you mean in the same context, and to represent the same Euclidean vector, I said in my previous comment that this is sloppiness. $\quad$ 2. The coordinate-representation thingy was a *given* from the outset of your Question (yes, a column vector is a slim matrix which is a data structure, and contains x,y,z components of an Euclidean vector), and so what? That is independent of the fact that, if notation is carefully adhered to (as shown in this Answer's final paragraph),

Comment: then that fake equality that was troubling you doesn't arise; this inconsistency is the thesis of your current Question, and I've shown how it is actually due to notation/misunderstanding. $\quad$ 3. BTW, get rid of the notion that the directed line segment (i.e., arrow) is the real vector and that that 3x1 matrix (i.e., column vector) is just its representation; a vector is an abstract object and both are valid manifestations of it; in $\mathbb R^7,$ which representation is more practical? heh.

Answer (score 4):

A vector is an element of a vector space. A vector space is a set that satisfies a few specific requirements.

The set of $m \times n$ matrices with entries from a field $\mathbb{F}$ is always a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, so all $m \times n$ matrices are vectors, including $m \times 1$ and $1 \times n$ row and column vectors.

As it so happens, there are *also* relationships between vector spaces - for example, the transpose of an $m \times n$ matrix is an $n \times m$ matrix, so we can say that $^T: \mathbb{F}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n \times m}$ is a relation between those two vector spaces. There is also a relation between $m \times n$ matrices and a plain old vector from $\mathbb{F}^{mn}$ where you write the elements of the matrix out into the components of the vector one at a time. If the relationship:

1. Is bijective (i.e. it maps every vector from the domain to exactly one vector from the codomain and vice versa), and
2. Preserves all of the vector space properties on each side (e.g. $(v_1 + v_2)^T = v_1^T + v_2^T$),

then the relation is called an *isomorphism*, and the two vector spaces are said to be *isomorphic*, and when two things are isomorphic you can essentially treat them as the same thing - as long as you only care about properties that pass through the isomorphism.

So yes - column vectors and row vectors *are* vectors, and they *are* equivalent to normal Euclidean vectors, as long as you're just talking about them as vectors. They *also* happen to be matrices, so you can do matrix things with them, but you need more sophisticated language if you want to relate those things to each other consistently since "doing matrix things" isn't necessarily covered by the vector space axioms.

As a small side note, you may not have even realised but you've already been bamboozled by isomorphic vector spaces, because that's what happens when you connect things written as $(x, y)$ with arrows drawn on a blackboard. Technically, one of those is just a pair of numbers inside a set of brackets while the other is a geometric construction, but we tend to just take it as granted that they're the "same" vectors because all the operations we want to do with them behave nicely across the divide so there's no point in making a real distinction.

Answer (score 0):

We could think of $\mathbb R^n$ as row vectors which is consistent with the tuple notation we use in high school or multi-variable calculus. However, our function notation places the symbol for the function to the left of its arguments and, since linear functions on finite dimensional vector spaces are represented by matrices, we need a vector $x$ to be a column vector for an expression like $Ax$ to make sense.

Therefore, in linear algebra, we use column vectors for points in our space and row vectors as points in the dual space.